# I am not able to change TcxGrid fields values when dataset in insert mode

Tags: delphi, dataset, tcxgrid

I am using delphi2010 and oracle 10g as a database

My TcxGrid is conected to dataset (qryDONEMSEL -> TOraQuery) when I want to add something to database by clicking button I change dataset to insert mode BUT the fields in TcxGrid are not enabled what is the problem ?

Code inside button as follow

```
if (qryDONEMSEL.RecordCount = 0) then
  begin

    qryDONEMSEL.Insert;
    qryDONEMSEL.FieldByName('YIL').asinteger := STRTOINT(Util.GETSQL('SELECT OGIS.AKTIFYIL FROM DUAL'));
    qryDONEMSEL.FieldByName('donem').asinteger := STRTOINT(Util.GETSQL('SELECT OGIS.AKTIFDONEM FROM DUAL'));
    qryDONEMSEL.FieldByName('DURUM').AsString := 'ST1';
    // qryDONEMSEL.FieldByName('sinif').ASstring := 'C2';
    // qryDONEMSEL.FieldByName('okudugu_somestre').ASinteger := 1;
    // 9 - Transfer kayıt sebebi
    if (POS('9', qryOGR.FieldByName('kay_sebep').AsString) > 0) then
    begin
      showmessage(gsLabels('Öğrenci transfer olarak kayıtlı.', self, 'OGIS') + #13#10 + gsLabels('Sınıf ve Sömestresini dikkatli ve doğru girin.', self, 'OGIS'));
    end;
  end
```

Can anyone advice me something ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
It is because in one function there was a line as below that disables fields.
grdDonemselView.columns[i].Options.Editing := False;
or change to 
grdDonemselView.columns[i].Options.Editing := True;
solved the problem